# WP Search Form Query: Add Author's posts into search query

Tags: customization, query, search

As the title suggests, I'm looking for WordPress advice relative to leveraging the standard `searchform.php` functionality to additionally query the `author` field when performing searches. I've tried various different means to do this without any success, and so I'm coming to quite the headache. Below are the template files used:

`searchform.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying search forms in Twenty Seventeen
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

?>

<?php $unique_id = esc_attr( uniqid( 'search-form-' ) ); ?>

<div class="global-search">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>">
      <span class="screen-reader-text sr-only"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'sdwp' ); ?></span>
    </label>
    <input type="search" id="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>" class="search-field" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
    <button type="submit" class="search-btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><span class="screen-reader-text sr-only"><?php echo _x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'sdwp' ); ?></span></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

`functions.php` - the bit of code I've written up after much reiteration

```
function add_author_to_query( $query ) {

  //do not run on admin side
  if( is_admin() ) return;

  if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {

    $submitted_data = get_search_query();

    // Get all users who may match the submitted data
    $users = new WP_User_Query( array(
      'search' => $submitted_data,
      'search_columns' => array( 'user_login', 'user_nicename')
    ) );
    $authors = $users->get_results();

    foreach($authors as $author) {
      $author_ids[] = $author->ID;
    }

    if( ! empty( $authors ) ) {
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'article', 'page', 'bio', 'author', 'article_type'));
        $query->set( 'author__in', $author_ids );
        // $query->set( 'author__in', $authors );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_author_to_query' );
```

Comment: Here, this should help: https://gist.github.com/danielbachhuber/7126249 ... updated 5 months ago and recommended by this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32958303/2510939)

Comment: @admcfajn tysm for commenting this. This solved my answer. It looks like I was using the wrong hook.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. Thanks for letting me know [TheNotSoGreatProgrammer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/222707/thenotsogreatprogrammer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that stumbles upon this, @admcfajn posted a comment to my question which solved my problem. Below is the code block found in the commented link, attributed to "danielbachhuber" github user:

```
/**
 * Include posts from authors in the search results where
 * either their display name or user login matches the query string
 *
 */
function db_filter_authors_search( $posts_search ) {

    // Don't modify the query at all if we're not on the search template or if the LIKE is empty
    if ( !is_search() || empty( $posts_search ) ) return $posts_search;

    global $wpdb;

    // Get all of the users of the blog and see if the search query matches either the display name or the user login
    add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'db_filter_user_query' );

    $search = sanitize_text_field( get_query_var( 's' ) );

    $args = array(
        'count_total' => false,
        'search' => sprintf( '*%s*', $search ),
        'search_fields' => array(
            'display_name',
            'user_login',
        ),
        'fields' => 'ID',
    );

    $matching_users = get_users( $args );

    remove_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'db_filter_user_query' );

    // Don't modify the query if there aren't any matching users
    if ( empty( $matching_users ) ) return $posts_search;

    // Take a slightly different approach than core where we want all of the posts from these authors
    $posts_search = str_replace( ')))', ")) OR ( {$wpdb->posts}.post_author IN (" . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $matching_users ) ) . ")))", $posts_search );
    return $posts_search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'db_filter_authors_search' );

/**
 * Modify get_users() to search display_name instead of user_nicename. Helper function used inside of db_filter_authors_search()
 */
function db_filter_user_query( &$user_query ) {

    if ( is_object( $user_query ) )
        $user_query->query_where = str_replace( "user_nicename LIKE", "display_name LIKE", $user_query->query_where );
    return $user_query;
}
```

** minor adjustments have been made by me, in the form of spacing and consolidating lines, to make the code more legible.